# Qual nome se dá a modelagem/notação de código?

Tags: pseudocódigo

Sei que a pergunta ficou meio estranha, mas é o seguinte:

Tem um tipo de notação que não é nenhuma linguagem, mas ela serve como base para implementar em alguma linguagem. por exemplo o algoritmo de [Dijkstra](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Dijkstra) está representado assim:

```
enquanto Q ≠ ø
     u ← extrair-mín(Q)                     //Q ← Q - {u}
     para cada v adjacente a u
          se d[v] > d[u] + w(u, v)          //relaxe (u, v)
             então d[v] ← d[u] + w(u, v)
                   π[v] ← u
                   Q ← Q ∪ {v}
```

**Qual o nome deste tipo de modelagem?**

Eu preciso representar um código que será implementado em várias linguagens, por qual nome devo pesquisar?

Comment: Seria pseudo-código?

Comment: Pseudocódigo, português estruturado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AnislanWesley, acredito que o que procura seja simplesmente um pseudocódigo mesmo.

Costuma-se achar pela internet varios tipos de pseudocódigos, cada um com uma sintaxe caracteristica. Quando aprendi a programar eu aprendi por um conhecido como [Portugol](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portugol) que tenta basicamente descrever as ações com simples português.

Mas você pode encontrar por ai, varias sintaxes de pseudocódigo baseadas em alguma linguagem em especifico, como C, Pascal, entre outras.

Inclusive, se você for trabalhar com matemática computacional por exemplo, os pseudocódigos encontram uma notação influenciada pela notação matemática, contendo SOMATORIOS por exemplo pra representar um `loop for`, por exemplo.

Enfim, acho que você pode encontrar uma que atenda as suas necessidades ou até mesmo crie a sua própria.

Answer (score 5):

Pseudocódigo, em português.

Em inglês, pseudocode.

Answer (score 3):

Geralmente este conceito está relacionado a uma DSL (Linguagem de Domínio Específico - http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_de_dom%C3%ADnio_espec%C3%ADfico).

Conceito: uma técnica de representação de problema particular.

Comment: Gostei do conceito, mas não responde, o meu problema é bem genérico. Preciso de um modelo em inglês que possa ser implementado em Java, C#, C++, Javascript..