# O que está errado neste pseudo-code?

Tags: pseudocódigo

Quem está acompanhando o sof-br viu que perguntei algo sobre **pseudo-code** algumas horas atraz ([aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16459/qual-nome-se-da-a-modelagem-notacao-de-codigo) se quiser acompanhar o contexto)

Bom, eu preciso fazer um pseudo-code em inglês que sirva de base para implementar este **[código](https://github.com/AnisanWesley/Anisoket)** em Java, C# e C++, Javascript e outras linguagens ([algumas já implementadas](https://github.com/AnisanWesley/Anisoket/tree/master/src)).

Então me aventurei a fazer este pseudo-code, mas não sei se ele está correto, podem me dizer como fazer para deixa-lo mais íntegro e condizente com a realidade? Está certo? O que mudar?

```
STRUCTURE TYPECONNECTION
Client 
Server
END TYPECONNECTION

VARIABLES
TypeConnection,
NetworkStream,
Writer,
Reader,
Server,
Client,
Ip,
Port
IsStarted
ENDVARIABLES

STRUCTURE SOKETSUPPORT

PROCEDURE CONFIGURE
    SWICH TypeConnection
        CASE TypeConnection is Server
            initialize server with ip and port
            start Server
        END CASE
        CASE TypeConnection is Client
            initialize client
        END CASE
    END SWICH
END CONFIGURE

RETURNS true
END CONFIGURE 

PROCEDURE SENDDATA(data)

    TRY
        IF
            SWITCH TypeConnection
                CASE TypeConnection is Server
                    write data in Writer
                    flushes writer 
                    closes soket
                END CASE    
                CASE TypeConnection is Client
                    initialize client with ip and port
                    initialize NetworkStream
                    initialize Writer
                    initialize Reader
                    IF Client is connected
                        write data in Writer
                        flushes writer
                    END IF
                END CASE
            END SWITCH
        END IF
        RETURNS IsStarted
    END TRY
    CATCH
        RETURNS false
    END CATCH

END SENDDATA

PROCEDURE RECEIVEDATA
    TRY
        IF IsStarted
        SWITCH TypeConnection
            CASE TypeConnection is server
                Accept socket
                initialize NetworkStrem with socket
                initialize Reader with NetworkStrem
                RETURNS Reader's reading
            END CASE
            CASE TypeConnection is client
                RETURNS Reader's reading
                close client
            END CASE
        END SWITCH
        END IF
    END TRY
    CATCH
        RETURNS Exception message
    END CATCH
END RECEIVEDATA

END SOKETSUPPORT
```

Comment: Se isso é pseudocódigo, a única coisa errada que vejo é que soquete em inglês se escreve *SOCKET* com 'c'. E o programa sempre vai retornar `true`. Não vejo utilidade em retornar sempre o mesmo valor constante, principalmente quando é um valor primitivo como o valor para verdadeiro, i.e.: eu posso tranquilamente ignorar o retorno do programa porque sempre vai dar no mesmo.

Comment: Mas a estrutura de um pseudo-code é isso ai mesmo então? Não tem uma forma certa ou errada de escrever?

Comment: Não existe uma forma de pseudocódigo "oficial", então não dá pra discutir sintaxe nem semântica. Fora isso, você demonstra como quer montar uma estrutura de dados com clareza e precisão.

Comment: hmm, muito obrigado, achei que tinha algum padrão porque pesquisei e não encontrei, então responde que não há padrão definido que marco como certa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe uma linguagem de pseudo-código "oficial". Existem várias formas diferentes de se expressar textualmente sobre como uma estrutura deve ser, ou como deve se comportar; mas como pseudocódigo não é interpretado nem compilado por uma máquina, qualquer tentativa de apontar um erro no estilo tende ao pedantismo. O mais importante é que a forma das estruturas e a lógica das operações sejam claras.

No entanto, vários cursos de programação tentam introduzir uma gramática ao pseudocódigo, o que acho um tanto forçoso. Nesses casos, recomendo seguir o padrão do curso, mas sem perder noites de sono por causa disso.